# Bad edit to sudoers file on EC2 instance, how to fix it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, configuration

While writing a script to edit the sudoers file without using `visudo`, the script did not check for issue, and I have introduced some bad edits into the `sudoers` file, and thus cannot use sudo at all anymore. (I know I did a very bad thing, and should probably have used something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28382838/4121573))

**Question**: Is there anyway I can recover from this mistake, or do I have to destroy the VM and start from scratch with a new one?

Comment: you can download some sample sudoers file and make sudoers work.

Comment: @KlwntSingh True, but without access to the `sudo` command, the ec2-user cannot perform any root command, which is the core of the issue (perhaps it was confusing!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about user-data ?

I believe adding the "#cloud-boothook" allow to force the user-data to run at every restart.

```
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test' > /home/ec2-user/user-script-output.txt
```

If so, you could fix your sudo scripts hopefully... or install / add AWS run commands configuration https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/

For sure if it is an EBS Drive, you can detach & fix and then re-attach on the original system. A bit of a pain though.

Answer (score 4):

Generally recovering from this sort of mistake involves editing the boot loader to force a root shell. Since you don't have physical access to the (non-physical) machine, things are a bit different.

If this is an EBS boot drive, you can try [detaching it, fixing it on another machine, then reattaching](https://serverfault.com/a/235824/12214).

This is a good opportunity to learn why it's useful to use configuration management tools for everything: if you were doing this, you could replace the instance in just a few minutes and one command.

Comment: On some circumstances, detached root volume couldn't be reattached to same machine. This can be avoided by creating a snapshot of detached volume (either before or after removing it from instance) and a volume from this snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the root password, typically you can type "su" to switch to a super-user. You can then edit your sudoers file to fix sudo.

Comment: I know, however I never assigned a password to the root account, thus my question...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root access by using the `su` command as `sudo` doesn't seem to be usable and then make appropriate changes. Now for the most important point:

*Always use* **visudo** *to edit sudoers file*

Why? It tells you if there are any errors after you made changes hence preventing one from messing up `sudo` access.

> To resolve broken `sudo` follow [this](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo) guide.

*This may not be possible in virtual compute.

Answer (score 1):

Detach the root volume, attach it to a running instance and restore the sudoers file in the volume. 
Detach the volume and re-attach to the instance in question and restart it.
This should work.